# Logistic Regression Coefficients Interpretation for Land Use Prediction Modeling Using MOLUSCE Plugin on QGIS

Tags: qgis, land-use, model, driving, logistic-regression

I was trying to model a Land-use prediction map using MOLUSCE Plugin on QGIS. For the input, there are 2 land-use data (2011 and 2016). Each land-use consists of 7 land-use classes (0 to 6). There are 4 driving factors for the prediction, namely distance to roads, distance to the city center, slope, and population density.

For the transition potential modeling, I used Logistic Regression on MOLUSCE. I have obtained the coefficients for the logistic regression, but I was confused because I only used 4 driving factors yet there are many coefficients generated that consist of B0 until B81 as shown in the attached image.

What do those coefficients mean?

I can't find any explanation in the manual or from other literature.

[image: Logistic regression result on MOLUSCE plugin]

[image: The logistic regression coefficients after being opened on excel - 1]

[image: The logistic regression coefficients after being opened on excel - 2]

[image: The logistic regression coefficients after being opened on excel - 3]